# Strange Random BSODs on Laptop

Tags: windows, bsod

**Firstly laptop's specs :**

**CPU :** Core i7 11800-h

**RAM :** 32gb ram

**GPU :** Nvidia RTX 3070

**SSD :** 2x Crucial P2 1TB PCIe M.2 2280SS

Using latest Windows 11 Home Edition (21H2 22000.795). Operating system was fresh installed, all updates are installed, all vendor specific drivers are installed.

Apart from these everyday use apps are installed. (like Chrome browser, VLC media player and etc.)

**Problem is :** Totally random BSODs generated at totally random times. I will give detailed information about last generated BSOD below. (Used WinDbg on full Memory dump)

```
  Microsoft (R) Windows Debugger Version 10.0.25136.1001 AMD64 Copyright
  (c) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.
  
  
  Loading Dump File [C:\Windows\MEMORY.DMP] Kernel Bitmap Dump File:
  Full address space is available
  
  Dump completed successfully, progress percentage: 100
  
  Symbol search path is: srv* Executable search path is:  Windows 10
  Kernel Version 22000 MP (16 procs) Free x64 Product: WinNt, suite:
  TerminalServer SingleUserTS Personal Edition build lab:
  22000.1.amd64fre.co_release.210604-1628 Machine Name: Kernel base = 0xfffff806`52e00000 PsLoadedModuleList = 0xfffff806`53a29650 Debug
  session time: Fri Jul 22 20:40:00.373 2022 (UTC + 3:00) System Uptime:
  0 days 4:33:52.550 Loading Kernel Symbols
  ...............................................................
  ................................................................
  ................................................................
  ................................ Loading User Symbols
  ...................... Loading unloaded module list
  .......................... For analysis of this file, run !analyze -v
  nt!KeBugCheckEx: fffff806`53217d00 48894c2408      mov     qword ptr
  [rsp+8],rcx ss:0018:ffffad0c`0a226d30=000000000000004c 5: kd !analyze
  -v
  *******************************************************************************
  *                                                                             *
  *                        Bugcheck Analysis                                    *
  *                                                                             *
  *******************************************************************************
  
  WINLOGON_FATAL_ERROR (c000021a) The Winlogon process terminated
  unexpectedly. Arguments: Arg1: ffffd30526da1040, String that
  identifies the problem. Arg2: ffffffffc0000006, Error Code. Arg3:
  00007ffe7347535e Arg4: 000000a12833db40
  
  Debugging Details:
  ------------------
  
  
  KEY_VALUES_STRING: 1
  
      Key  : Analysis.CPU.mSec
      Value: 2875
  
      Key  : Analysis.DebugAnalysisManager
      Value: Create
  
      Key  : Analysis.Elapsed.mSec
      Value: 19202
  
      Key  : Analysis.Init.CPU.mSec
 
     Value: 952
 
     Key  : Analysis.Init.Elapsed.mSec
     Value: 102321
 
     Key  : Analysis.Memory.CommitPeak.Mb
     Value: 114
 
     Key  : Bugcheck.Code.DumpHeader
     Value: 0xc000021a
 
     Key  : Bugcheck.Code.KiBugCheckData
     Value: 0xc000021a
 
     Key  : Bugcheck.Code.Register
     Value: 0x4c
 
     Key  : Dump.Attributes.AsUlong
     Value: 1800
 
     Key  : WER.OS.Branch
     Value: co_release
 
     Key  : WER.OS.Timestamp
     Value: 2021-06-04T16:28:00Z
 
     Key  : WER.OS.Version
     Value: 10.0.22000.1
 
 
 FILE_IN_CAB:  MEMORY.DMP
 
 TAG_NOT_DEFINED_202b:  *** Unknown TAG in analysis list 202b
 
 
 ERROR_CODE: (NTSTATUS) 0xc000021a - { nemli Sistem Hatas }  %hs sistem
 i lemi, 0x
 
 EXCEPTION_CODE_STR:  c000021a
 
 EXCEPTION_PARAMETER1:  ffffd30526da1040
 
 EXCEPTION_PARAMETER2:  ffffffffc0000006
 
 EXCEPTION_PARAMETER3:  00007ffe7347535e
 
 EXCEPTION_PARAMETER4: a12833db40
 
 DUMP_FILE_ATTRIBUTES: 0x1800
 
 BUGCHECK_CODE:  c000021a
 
 BUGCHECK_P1: ffffd30526da1040
 
 BUGCHECK_P2: ffffffffc0000006
 
 BUGCHECK_P3: 7ffe7347535e
 
 BUGCHECK_P4: a12833db40
 
 PROCESS_NAME:  csrss.exe
 
 ADDITIONAL_DEBUG_TEXT:  Windows SubSystem
 
 IMAGE_NAME:  ntkrnlmp.exe
 
 MODULE_NAME: nt
 
 BLACKBOXBSD: 1 (!blackboxbsd)
 
 
 BLACKBOXNTFS: 1 (!blackboxntfs)
 
 
 BLACKBOXPNP: 1 (!blackboxpnp)
 
 
 BLACKBOXWINLOGON: 1
 
 STACK_TEXT:   ffffad0c`0a226d28 fffff806`538672af     :
 00000000`0000004c 00000000`c000021a ffffad0c`0a1a6cd8
 ffff8888`8c57e090 : nt!KeBugCheckEx ffffad0c`0a226d30
 fffff806`538581b6     : 00000000`00000000 ffffad0c`0a226df0
 ffffffff`8000396c 00000000`00000000 : nt!PopGracefulShutdown+0x2af
 ffffad0c`0a226d70 fffff806`5384e8dc     : 00000000`00000001
 00000000`00000006 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000005 :
 nt!PopTransitionSystemPowerStateEx+0x132be ffffad0c`0a226e30
 fffff806`5322a275     : fffff806`00000001 fffff806`00000000
 00000000`00000002 fffff806`5308fbc7 : nt!NtSetSystemPowerState+0x4c
 ffffad0c`0a227000 fffff806`5321c550     : fffff806`536de9ac
 00000000`00000014 ffffffff`ffffff00 fffff806`53a1fa98 :
 nt!KiSystemServiceCopyEnd+0x25 ffffad0c`0a227198 fffff806`536de9ac    
 : 00000000`00000014 ffffffff`ffffff00 fffff806`53a1fa98
 00000000`00000000 : nt!KiServiceLinkage ffffad0c`0a2271a0
 fffff806`535ef760     : ffffe600`c5940180 00000000`00000080
 ffff8888`89769380 fffff806`530334d9 : nt!PopIssueActionRequest+0xeee84
 ffffad0c`0a227240 fffff806`53145d89     : 00000000`00000001
 00000000`00000000 ffffffff`ffffffff fffff806`53b33680 :
 nt!PopPolicyWorkerAction+0x80 ffffad0c`0a2272c0 fffff806`53032eaf    
 : ffff8888`00000001 ffff8888`89769380 fffff806`53a23020
 fffff806`00000000 : nt!PopPolicyWorkerThread+0xa9 ffffad0c`0a227300
 fffff806`53130415     : ffff8888`89769380 ffffe600`c5950000
 ffff8888`89769380 0000adf3`0000d1f2 : nt!ExpWorkerThread+0x14f
 ffffad0c`0a2274f0 fffff806`5321bdb4     : ffffe600`c5940180
 ffff8888`89769380 fffff806`531303c0 00003000`00003e01 :
 nt!PspSystemThreadStartup+0x55 ffffad0c`0a227540 00000000`00000000    
 : ffffad0c`0a228000 ffffad0c`0a221000 00000000`00000000
 00000000`00000000 : nt!KiStartSystemThread+0x34
 
 
 SYMBOL_NAME:  nt!PopTransitionSystemPowerStateEx+132be
 
 STACK_COMMAND:  .cxr; .ecxr ; kb
 
 BUCKET_ID_FUNC_OFFSET:  132be
 
 FAILURE_BUCKET_ID: 
 0xc000021a_c0000006_csrss.exe_Terminated_nt!PopTransitionSystemPowerStateEx
 
 OS_VERSION:  10.0.22000.1
 
 BUILDLAB_STR:  co_release
 
 OSPLATFORM_TYPE:  x64
 
 OSNAME:  Windows 10
 
 FAILURE_ID_HASH:  {b3ffc8fa-795c-38e6-3bd9-0b1e1680adf3}
 
 Followup:     MachineOwner
 ---------
 
 5: kd dc ffffd30526da1040 ffffd305`26da1040  646e6957 2073776f
 53627553 65747379  Windows SubSyste ffffd305`26da1050  0053006d
 00000041 00000000 00000000  m.S.A........... ffffd305`26da1060 
 03030000 20206553 00000000 00000000  ....Se  ........
 ffffd305`26da1070  26da1080 ffffd305 00000000 00000000 
 ...&............ ffffd305`26da1080  00000101 05000000 00000012
 00000000  ................ ffffd305`26da1090  03030000 64536553
 00000000 00000000  ....SeSd........ ffffd305`26da10a0  001c0002
 00000001 00140011 00000001  ................ ffffd305`26da10b0 
 00000101 10000000 00004000 00000000  .........@...... 5: kd da
 ffffd30526da1040 ffffd305`26da1040  "Windows SubSystem"
```

Before this BSOD, i got a BSOD like "Microsoft Store Component unexpectedly closed/crashed" I do not remember exactly.

**What I tried :**

-Tested rams with various test applications like (Memtest). No problem found.

-Tested CPU with varius test applications like (Prime95) no problem found.

-Tested GPU with various test applications like (Furmark) no problem found.

-Tested SSD s with various test applications like (hdtune) and no problem/badblock found. Also did a test with a vendor application and no problem found. S.M.A.R.T values indicates no problems.

-Did a stress test with varius applications for long time and nothing crashed.

-Scanned whole system with various anti-virus/spyware applications nothing found.

-Tried all of system repair commands like (sfc scannow) nothing found.

-Fresh installed OS + vendor drivers again and problem continues.

BSOD types are changing and PC crashes at totally random times. Sometimes i play very hardware demanding games for hours without a single crash but sometimes when i left PC idle and it crashes.

What else I can try? I have full memory dumps about BSODS.

Comment: > WINLOGON_FATAL_ERROR (c000021a) The Winlogon process terminated unexpectedly. Arguments: Arg1: ffffd30526da1040, String that identifies the problem. Arg2: ffffffffc0000006, Error Code. Arg3: 00007ffe7347535e Arg4: 000000a12833db40<

This is the bit that jumps out, I'd do some searching on windows forums. Looks like it could be a windows 11 feature. Someone else posted a question about corrupt local accounts recently. Or it could be failing to connect to MS telemetry/call home servers.

Comment: A 30GB os install and still no plain-language error logs. WINning.

Comment: Please do not use citations for code or output, as it nearly allways messes up the formatting. Instead use the dedicated code tags, they will display the text correctly regardless of the whitespaces or special symbols it contains. I've edited your question with codetags to restore readability